# How to use useRouter() in order to import a file in NextJS/React

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, import

I'm having a problem in using useRouter() in order to import specific files under a certain condition. I'm aware it's impossible to use a useHook outside of a function component. However I'm quite sure there is a way to puzzle out this problem.

I'm navigating to a pathname with a query object which holds two properties:

1. D (DocNum)
2. T (Type)

```
<Link href={{ pathname: `/orders/preview/${row.DocEntry}`, query: { D: row.DocNum, T: "order" } }} passHref>
        <StyledLink>{`#${row.DocNum}`}</StyledLink>
      </Link>
```

Now, I want to import particular files if the type is equal to "order". So, if I have developed the following condition:

```
let PdfTest;
let Actions;
let DisputesNum;
let ServiceDrawer;
let fetchDisputesTest;
let pdfDataTest;


// Test
if("order" === "order"){
  import('src/views/preview/previewComponents/PdfPreviewCard')
  .then((pdf) => {
     PdfTest = pdf.default;
  });
  import('src/views/preview/previewComponents/PreviewActions')
  .then((action) => {
     Actions = action.default;
  });
  import('src/views/preview/previewComponents/Disputes')
  .then((dispute) => {
     DisputesNum = dispute.default;
  });

  import('src/views/preview/shared-drawer/AddServiceCallDrawer')
  .then((drawer) => {
    ServiceDrawer = drawer.default;
  });

  import('src/store/orders').then((module) => {
    fetchDisputesTest = module.fetchDisputes;
    pdfDataTest = module.pdfData;
  });
}
```

It's obvious I'm trying to import these files if order is equal to order which is just a test, as I can't use the useRouter react-hook outside of the component function, in order to develop a condition which helps me import these files if the query type is equal to orders.

I just want to know if there's a way to import these files using the useRouter, or any other way?

```
const router = useRouter();

const type = router.query.T;
```

I tried to use useRouter outside the function component in numerous ways. However, I'd failed to solve out this problem.